# What to do when "it" is redundant?

Tags: grammar, phrases, pronouns

I'm writing a list of terms. Every term has its own definition. The scheme is:

Term: short definition. Long definition.

eg.

> **HTTP:** short for HyperText Transfer Protocol (http://). It is a protocol to see web pages, used by the World Wide Web to exchange data
>   between your browser and a website.
>
> **HTTPS:** short for HyperText Transfer Protocol Secure (https://). It is a more secure version of the HTTP.
>
> **Google Adsense:** is an advertising program from Google. It allows publishers to display ads on website pages.
>
> **Website:** also known as web site, site. It is a collection of web pages accessible via the Internet.

Reading the terms from beginning to the end, the "It is a [...]" sounds redundant. Is it correct if in some sentence I use only "Is a [...]"?

Comment: Define *correct*. This is not an English question. It's a writing style question. You are apparently writing a glossary. What does your style guide tell you about the style to use for that?

Comment: it's an English question: the question is if it's ok to omit some words in a sentence. It's very idiomatic and part of the language.

Comment: This is really pedantic, but HTTPS does not stand for HyperText Transfer Protocol Secure; it stands for HTTP over SSL (Secure Sockets Layer). Except we don't use SSL anymore, we use TLS (Transport Layer Security), and we just didn't bother changing it.

Comment: From wiki: HTTPS (also called HTTP over TLS, HTTP over SSL, and HTTP Secure).
I'll add to the description. And yes, we still call SSL the new protocol called TLS. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need to use full sentences when writing definitions. The implied subject is the term which is being defined, and the implied verb is an expression of equivalency (generally the verb is assumed to be "is"). You seem to already realize this in the first part of each definition.

> **HTTP:** short for HyperText Transfer Protocol (http://).

Here you are allowing the term "HTTP" to serve as the subject, and leaving the verb (is) unstated. As long as your editor or instructor has not given you specific instructions to the contrary, you can safely leave the subject and verb implied for the entire definition.

> **HTTP:** short for HyperText Transfer Protocol (http://). A protocol to see web pages, used by the World Wide Web to exchange data between your browser and a website.

Most dictionaries do not use full stops in definitions, so it may be better to use a comma or semicolon (as appropriate).

Also, be careful to be consistent. You have included the verb "is" in your definition of Google AdSense, but the equivalency verb should be left implied in a definition.

It may be helpful to spend a bit of time looking at the structure of entries in popular English dictionaries if you would like to gain a little more confidence.

Comment: I'll take your suggestion and look at the dictionary. While I'm not sure if I'll drop the period between the short description and the long one, I'll definitely drop the pronoun and verb.

Comment: You can also use a semicolon or a double dash.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps a simple rewording will work instead of specifically replacing "It is a"

> **HTTP**: short for HyperText Transfer Protocol (http://), a protocol to see web pages that is used by the World Wide Web to exchange data between your browser and a website.
>
> **HTTPS**: short for HyperText Transfer Protocol Secure (https://), a more secure version of the HTTP.
>
> **Google Adsense**: an advertising program from Google, allowing publishers to display ads on website pages.
>
> **Website**: a collection of web pages accessible via the Internet, also referred to as a "site" for short.

Answer (score 4):

*Reading the terms from beginning to the end, the "It is a [...]" sounds redundant. Is it correct if in some sentence I use only "Is a [...]"?*

No, it is not correct. English is not a pronoun-dropping (pro-drop) language. You can drop both the subject and the verb in a context where noun phrases are acceptable in place of sentences, such as in a glossary like yours, or in speech:

"What is a website?" "A collection of web pages."

But you can never drop only the subject:

* "Is a collection of web pages."

or only the verb:

* "It a collection of web pages."

Comment: Thank you, I'm Italian, so in my language it is possible, that's why sometimes I'm in doubt. I'll use either the pronoun+verb or none of them, as suggested in the other answers.